# Can I cache my manually-calculated dialog base units? Can I use the same calculations for all windows with the same font?

Tags: c, winapi, resize, dpi, gdi

Right now, in my Windows API code, I am grabbing the dialog base units for each window on each resize:

```
// error checking elided
dc = GetDC(hwnd);
SelectObject(dc, controlFont); // non-client metrics lfMessageFont loaded at startup and never changed again
GetTextMetricsW(dc, &tm);
baseY = tm.tmHeight;
// and either tm.tmAveCharWidth or the GetTextExtentPoint32W() approach for baseX
ReleaseDC(hwnd, dc);
```

I want to simplify my resizing code, which IMHO is a mess because of all this extra work needed only on Windows. To do that, I need to know two things:

- Can I safely assume that these values will never change (assuming `controlFont` does not change)?

  - If they can change if the current DPI is changed, can I be notified as such? Does Windows support multi-monitor multi-DPI? IIRC Windows 8.1+ can with some manifests; is there a way I can override the manifests (as this is a library) or some safe way I can write for such a setup? What about having a window halfway in one DPI and halfway in another?
- Can I safely assume that these values are the same for all top-level windows I create?

  - If they can change if the current DPI is changed, then "for all top-level windows I create with the same DPI".

If the answer to both questions is "yes", or "yes, with some extra DPI/font detection messages", then I can get rid of the window-specific code in my resizing code, cleaning things up considerably. Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/coding-for-high-dpi-displays-in-windows/240168736

Comment: Interesting; at the moment, however, i need to target XP as a minimum, and the MSDN page on `SetProcessDpiAwareness()` strangely does not show what DLL it's in... Furthermore, this is a library; due to toolkit restrictions it has to be statically linked, and I cannot know if some other dependency will call this function...

Comment: Update: after various optimizations and refactors, I can return to getting the DC on each resize operation, so this question may lie dormant. Thanks anyway!